# Remove a directory when unzipping

Tags: gradle

I am unpacking a zip file into a directory.  The zip file has an extra top level directory that I don't want in the unzipped destination.

```
task unpackDojoSource(type: Copy) {
    new File("build/dojo/src").mkdirs()
    from(zipTree(dojoSource)) {
        eachFile { details -> details.path = 
           details.path.substring(details.relativePath.segments[0].length()) } 
    } into "build/dojo/src"
}
```

The task produces the following output

```
/dijit
/dojo
/dojo-release-1.7.2
   /dijit
   /dojo
   /dojox
   /util
/dojox
/util
```

Is there a way I can prevent the dojo-release directory from being created?

Ref:
http://gradle.markmail.org/thread/x6gmbrhhen63rybe#query:+page:1+mid:lws7nlqcncjumnvs+state:results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just ran across this myself.  I worked around it by doing a delete afterwards.  Less than ideal but still effective.

```
    delete "dojo-release-1.7.2"
```

Answer (score 3):

I just stumble upon the same problem. Only thing you need to do is to add `includeEmptyDirs = false` into your copy spec like this:

```groovy
task unpackDojoSource(type: Copy) {
    new File("build/dojo/src").mkdirs()
    from(zipTree(dojoSource)) {
        eachFile { details -> details.path = 
           details.path.substring(details.relativePath.segments[0].length()) } 
    } into "build/dojo/src"
    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```

The resulting structure will not contain the empty directories left by flattening.